# Get total number of posts in a WordPress Category (including subcategories)

Tags: wordpress, categories

I would like to count the total number of posts being displayed in the current loop.  This function is the closest that I have been able to find:

```
function wt_get_category_count($input = '') {
    global $wpdb;
    if($input == '')
    {
        $category = get_the_category();
        return $category[0]->category_count;
    }
    elseif(is_numeric($input))
    {
        $SQL = "SELECT $wpdb->term_taxonomy.count FROM $wpdb->terms, $wpdb->term_taxonomy WHERE $wpdb->terms.term_id=$wpdb->term_taxonomy.term_id AND $wpdb->term_taxonomy.term_id=$input";
        return $wpdb->get_var($SQL);
    }
    else
    {
        $SQL = "SELECT $wpdb->term_taxonomy.count FROM $wpdb->terms, $wpdb->term_taxonomy WHERE $wpdb->terms.term_id=$wpdb->term_taxonomy.term_id AND $wpdb->terms.slug='$input'";
        return $wpdb->get_var($SQL);
    }
}
```

Which is from: http://www.web-templates.nu/2008/09/21/get_category_count/

Unfortunately, it does not count the number of posts from the current category's subcategories.  Is there a way to do this?  Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer for anyone else with the same question - I've embedded it in a pager function.  In my case, it won't show up on the search page.

```
<?php previous_posts_link(' <&nbsp;Previous'); ?> 

<?php if (!is_search()) { ?>
There are <?php echo $wp_query->found_posts; ?> posts in the category "<?php 
    foreach((get_the_category()) as $category) 
        { 
      $postcat= $category->cat_ID; 
      $catname =$category->cat_name;
      echo $catname;
    } 
?>".
<?php } ?>
<?php next_posts_link('Next&nbsp;>'); ?>
```